# REST API backend for mobile application (android/iOS)

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I am developing a backend for mobile app. I have developed a user authentication module where, the app will be sending the username and password as basic auth and if the user is authenticated I will sent back a jwt token which can be used in the rest of the requests.

On the client side, once after a user is logged in, the app shows him a feeds screen which contains some data.

Now do I need to seperate these two APIs? Like once a user is logged in successfully, he will be sent back the jwt token and well some user details. Should I sent the data which is required for the dashboard screen as well as a response for login? In that the case the app will get datas in a single api request (login) and doest have to make another call to my API.

Is this a right approach?

Comment: I think you should split it in 2 calls, one to get only the token and other to use this token to get the private data. Return only some user related information like name, uuid etc. but not the main data that you want to show

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should be kept seperately but I think that depends. If making that single request is (and will ever be) the only thing the application does, I see no reason for making 2 requests. You can simplify things by making just 1 request.

But, if your application is going to be extended or if its already got other features i think it is best to keep them seperate. Since then you'll have more flexibility with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,You should separate those two authentication and dashboard REST API as-
It could be possible that there should be more client app using your Rest API in future and they may not require dashboard data.However you can have mechanism to share user detail in authentication API itself as you are anyway authenticating user .However share access token in authentication api along with it's expiration timestamp .Some of Client app which are using your REST API might have use case of autologout from app based on accesstoken get expire.In such case expiration time would help.